# symfony No engine is able to work with the template

Tags: symfony

I try to call a function from an api.

In my twig i call a js, and in this js i use a path :

```
var path    = "{{ path('rapport_mail_envoie') }}";
```

who call the function :

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/report/mail", name="rapport_mail_envoie")
 */
public function rapportMailEnvoieAction(){
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request("POST", $this->getParameter("host.api.prefix").$this->getParameter("host.api")."/fr_FR/surveillance/bo/rapport/ajax");
    return $res;
}
```

And this function get a post, but when i get this post i have this error :

```
No engine is able to work with the template
```

edit, solved :

```
return new Response($res->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: You should return a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`

Comment: Thanks that helped me to found the solution : return new Response($res->getBody()->getContents());